# Infer a field value from another field

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to set a struct’s field value depending on the value of another field.

This is the method I’ve arrived at, where I wait until `changeset` is called and slip it in between the validators. Is this the correct/expected method of doing something like this?

One issue with doing it this way is if someone writes `fruit = %Fruit(%{name: :lemon})`, they can’t access `fruit.tastes` until they save and load the record (or at least call some wrapper around `changeset` and `apply_changeset`). This isn’t a huge deal though, just a would-be-nice. The reason I’m not just using a `Fruit.tastes(fruit)` function is because tastes has to be indexable in the DB.

```
defmodule Food.Fruit do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  @required_attributes [:name]
  @optional_attributes []
  @valid_names [:lemon, :banana]
  @valid_tastes [:sour, :sweet]

  schema "fruits" do
    field :name, :string #user specified

    field :tastes, :string #inferred from name

    timestamps()
  end

  def changeset(fruit, attrs) do
    fruit
    |> cast(attrs, @required_attribtues ++ @optional_attributes)
    |> validate_required(@required_attributes)
    |> validate_inclusion(:name, @valid_names)
    |> infer_colour
    # these are debately needed, we should set things correctly in infer_colour
    # but perhaps doesn't hurt to check to ward against future stupid.
    |> validate_required(:tastes)
    |> validate_inclusion(:tastes, @valid_tastes)
  end

  # name is invalid, so we can't infer any value
  def infer_colour(%Ecto.Changeset{errors: [{:name, _} | _]} = changeset), do: changeset
  # name isn't error'd so we can infer a value
  def infer_colour(%Ecto.Changeset{} = changeset) do
    case fetch_field(changeset, :name) do
      # match on {:data, value} or {:changes, value} so if the user passes a
      # custom :tastes to Fruit.changeset we default to overwriting it
      # with our correct value (though cast(...) should be stripping :tastes if present)
      {_, :lemon} -> change(changeset, %{tastes: :sour})
      {_, :apple} -> change(changeset, %{tastes: :sweet})
      {_. name} -> add_error(changeset, :tastes, "unknown :tastes for #{name}")
      :error -> add_error(changeset, :tastes, "could not infer :tastes, no :name found")
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your solution has any issues, but did you consider adding :taste in attrs before casting, e.g.:

```
defmodule Food.Fruit do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  @required_attributes [:name]
  @optional_attributes []
  @valid_names [:lemon, :banana]
  @valid_tastes [:sour, :sweet]

  schema "fruits" do
    field :name, :string #user specified

    field :tastes, :string #inferred from name

    timestamps()
  end

  def changeset(fruit, attrs) do
    attrs = resolve_taste(attrs)
    fruit
    |> cast(attrs, @required_attribtues ++ @optional_attributes)
    |> validate_required(@required_attributes)
    |> validate_inclusion(:name, @valid_names)
    |> validate_required(:tastes)
    |> validate_inclusion(:tastes, @valid_tastes)
  end

  def resolve_taste(%{name: :lemon}=a), 
    do: Map.put_new(a, :tastes, :sour)
  def resolve_taste(%{name: :apple}=a),
    do: Map.put_new(a, :tastes, :sweet)
  def resolve_taste(any), do: any
end
```

should still validate correctly, and you don't need to worry if taste changes or not.

Comment: Err....Doh. That seems a lot simpler and nicely separates the setting from the validation. At least as long as you can be sure `:name` doesn't get committed to the DB outside of `changeset` – if you did then `attrs` wouldn't have a `:name` to resolve with. But I can't think of how you might get in that state unless you were _really_ doing something you shouldn't in the first place.

Comment: Don't forget you are using functional language, OOP principles doesn't apply here, so if one need to find how you did something, he/she needs to find that function! So rather think how to design function-ality :)